# How to loop url in array and print css selector element in driver, Python Selenium

Tags: python, loops, selenium-webdriver

Wants to find the number of sold of each product (given urls in array)
using selenium web driver

This is my code

```
urls=["https://shopee.com.my/Pantene-Shampoo-750ml-i.52968176.7669592698/","https://shopee.com.my/PureMAE-Ylang-Ylang-and-Grapefruit-Shampoo-250ML-i.238433989.4820842024/","https://shopee.com.my/Some-By-Mi-Cica-Peptide-Anti-Hair-Loss-Shampoo-285ml-Tonic-150ml-Treatment-50ml-i.18874494.3274522052/","https://shopee.com.my/-JULYME-Anti-Hair-Loss-Perfume-Hair-Shampoo-500ml-i.219158269.6815232839/"]

for url in urls:
  driver.get(url)
  print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.aca9MM').text)
```

expected result is :

3.4k
13
5.3k
1.9k

but I get error in line 5
and can only print out the first one 3.4k

----------------------------output------------------------------

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:6: DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead
  
3.4k

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-0468875b1355> in <module>()
      3 for url in urls:
      4   driver.get(url)
----> 5   print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.aca9MM').text)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    241                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    242             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
--> 243         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    244 
    245     def _value_or_default(self, obj: Mapping[_KT, _VT], key: _KT, default: _VT) -> _VT:

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div.aca9MM"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=95.0.4638.69)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x5607a4253623 <unknown>
#1 0x5607a3f5ad43 <unknown>
#2 0x5607a3f905f0 <unknown>
#3 0x5607a3fc4337 <unknown>
#4 0x5607a3fad5fd <unknown>
#5 0x5607a3fc20ac <unknown>
#6 0x5607a3fad9e3 <unknown>
#7 0x5607a3f84c0c <unknown>
#8 0x5607a3f860d5 <unknown>
#9 0x5607a4277954 <unknown>
#10 0x5607a4286f6d <unknown>
#11 0x5607a4286c8b <unknown>
#12 0x5607a42875b2 <unknown>
#13 0x5607a42bfe8b <unknown>
#14 0x5607a4287811 <unknown>
#15 0x5607a426c831 <unknown>
#16 0x5607a4290218 <unknown>
#17 0x5607a42903aa <unknown>
#18 0x5607a42aa3bf <unknown>
#19 0x7ffad38736db <unknown>
```

Comment: Please show the exact error message you are getting, including traceback.

Comment: @mkrieger1 just added, please have a look. thankss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
urls=["https://shopee.com.my/Pantene-Shampoo-750ml-i.52968176.7669592698/","https://shopee.com.my/PureMAE-Ylang-Ylang-and-Grapefruit-Shampoo-250ML-i.238433989.4820842024/","https://shopee.com.my/-JULYME-Anti-Hair-Loss-Perfume-Hair-Shampoo-500ml-i.219158269.6815232839/"]

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/YOURNAME/Desktop/chromedriver')

#for every url in the list of urls
try:
    for url in urls:
        driver.get(url)
        print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.aca9MM').text)

except:
    print("error")
```

```
3.4k

13

error
```

Seems like there is no div.aca9MM on the third URL that you provided.

Comment: i went to the inspect of the URL 
this is in there, it is the number of sold

<div class="aca9MM">5.4k</div>

Comment: Maybe make use of the sleep() function so that the script has some time to process. Also driver.close because closing the windows each time is bothering.

Comment: i added driver.implicitly_wait(), and it works!! thankyou for the tips

Comment: Oh that's great. Always make sure that you give the script time to breath.